# select features based on minimum score in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to select features within a pipeline.
My pipeline is the following:

I was thinking to use the

> Univariate feature selector with configurable strategy.

From the documentation:

```
class sklearn.feature_selection.GenericUnivariateSelect(score_func=<function f_classif>, mode=’percentile’, param=1e-05)

   score_func : callable

    Function taking two arrays X and y, and returning a pair of arrays (scores, pvalues). For modes ‘percentile’ or ‘kbest’ it can return a single array scores.
```

I have a custom score function, which fullfills these requirements.

```
mode : {‘percentile’, ‘k_best’, ‘fpr’, ‘fdr’, ‘fwe’}

    Feature selection mode.
```

But how do I add additional modes?
Possibly, without having to overriding classes on top of SelectorMixin

---

### EDIT

My pipline looks like:

```
from  sklearn.feature_selection import GenericUnivariateSelect

custom_filter=GenericUnivariateSelect(my_score)   
MyProcessingPipeline=Pipeline(steps=[('filter_step', custom_filter)])
```

My processing pipelines is as simple as:

```
X=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(500,3))
MyProcessingPipeline.fit(X)
MyProcessingPipeline.transform(X)
```

My score for what matters in this context is:

```
#Function taking two arrays X and y, and returning a pair of arrays (scores, pvalues). 
def my_score(X,y):
    return (np.random.rand(X.shape[1]),np.zeros((X.shape[1],1)))
```

In my case, I would  like the transform to keep all the features for which `my_score` returns a score `>0.6`.
How to obtain that?
I am more and more sure I will have to override some native sklearn classes, but does anyone have an idea which one should I override to minimize the amount of code to be written while at the same time being able to perform this very simple feature selection?

Comment: You should add more specificity to your question about what exactly do you want to do and also add complete code.

Comment: I think now I have added all the needed detail. I can not send you the complete source code I hope you can understand

Comment: Your question makes perfect sense, and I too would like to know how to select features based on a score threshold (rather than take K best etc.)